# Is it possible to design a generic many-to-many junction table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many

Let's say I want to design a naive application, which has the following three tables:

[image: basic]

There are two many-to-many relationship:

1. A customer may has many favourite avatars, an avatar may be used by many customers;
2. A product may has many product images, a product image may be used by many products;

So we could add two junction tables to accomplish the relationship above:

[image: junction-table]

The `customer_image` table closely resembles the `product_image` table, is it possible to create a generic junction table like the following?

[image]

As the `generic_map` table will be used by different models (customer, product and etc), I removed the foreign key constraints.

Any suggestion? thanks.

Comment: Once you have decided against a generic table, see [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) for more efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear *why* you would want to do this. What benefit does it give you over creating a separate table for each many-to-many relationship?

It also creates a lot of unnecessary complexity.

## Constraints

The fact that you *must* remove the foreign key constraints to make your table work should be a strong clue that this is a bad strategy.

## Duplicates

So if you do a join from the `image` table to the `generic_map.to_id` and find the image maps to a given value for `from_id`, such as 1234, how would you know if this value references a `customer` with id 1234, or a `product` with id 1234?

Normally a many-to-many mapping table has a UNIQUE constraint on the pair of columns that reference each entity. But in your `generic_map` can you have such a constraint?

What if both `customer` 1234 and `product` 1234 each want to map to the same image? Do you store the mapping row twice in the `generic_map` table? If so, what happens when you join from `customer` through `generic_map` to `image`? You'd get duplicates from the join.

Also, what if just the `customer` 1234 wants to reference a specific image, but the `product` with the same id 1234 does not want that image? How would you make it clear that the `product` 1234 should *not* join to that row in the `generic_map` table?

So you commented:

> I forgot to declare a `type` column in the `generic_table`, the `type` column is of type `ENUM('customer', 'product')`. Via this column, I could know a `generic.from_id` value of 1234 means customer id or product id.

But this leads into another problem...

## Queries

You must remember to put conditions on the extra `type` column on every query you run:

```
SELECT ...
FROM customer AS c
JOIN generic_map AS m ON c.id=m.from_id AND m.type='customer'
JOIN image AS i ON m.to_id
```

If you (or someone else on your team who maintains this code) forgets to include this condition, then you will get the strange effects I described above.

## Performance

Queries against smaller tables are usually faster. But now you are guaranteed to have a large table.

Suppose if you had separate tables, your customer_image table had 10,000,000 rows. Your product_image table had 1,000 rows. You should be concerned that your query for product image needs to search through 10,001,000 rows instead of 1,000 rows. Indexes can help, but it would be even better for performance if the tables were separate.

The above are just a few problems. They keep unraveling like a loose thread.

Do yourself a favor — just use two tables, one for each many-to-many relationship. It will make everything easier.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to declare a `type` column in the `generic_table`, the `type` column is of type `ENUM('customer', 'product')`. Via this column, I could know a `generic.from_id` value of  `1234` means customer id or product id. With the three columns (`type`, `from_id`, and `to_id`), there will be a _UNIQUE constraint_,  isn't it?

Comment: The direct reason of _my creating a `generic_map` table thought_ is that I want to decrease the number of junction tables in an applicaton. After reading your answer, I realized that it was not a right way. In a database schema, large number of juction tables is less important compared with performance and stability. Thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a generic table for the relation, But as a good database using separate tables for mapping is better.

If you want to use a generic table for mapping, you can create a `generic_map` table with fields `id`,`customer_id`,`image_id`,`product_id`.